# Combining $.each functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the $.each function in jQuery to assign and change classes and IDs on various elements on click. I was wondering if there is a way to combine these into a single function rather than having three separate functions.

```
var stored = $.each;

var myFunction = function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("id");
};

  function numbers() {

    //function 1
    stored($(".numbers"), function(index, value) {
        var num = index + 1 + ".";
        $(value).empty();
        $(value).append(num);
    });

    //function 2
    stored($(".weight-change"), function(index) {
        myFunction();
        $(this).attr("id", "weight" + index);
    });

    //function 3
    stored($(".onebox"), function(index) {
        myFunction();
        $(this).attr("id", "shipprice1box" + index);
    });
 }
```

Comment: They do different things to different elements...so not sure if it makes sense to combine them?

Comment: You can make it generic, also makes no sense to remove the id and you replace it...

Comment: I agree with the first comment.  Aside from fn2 and fn3, it doesn't really make sense to combine them all into one method.  Instead of having three concise pieces of code you'd end up with one piece of code with unnecessary conditionals to handle the different logic flows.  Forced combination of logic can often times reduce readability, which is important with promoting maintainability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic function and call it. There is no need to remove the attribute before you update it. Just a waste of processing time. `attr` supports a function so no need for each.

```
function updateIds (selector, prefix) {
    $(selector).attr("id", function (index) { return prefix + index; }); 
}

updateIds(".weight-change", "weight");
updateIds(".onebox", "shipprice1box");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can avoid code duplication (you can edit it further according to your needs).

```
var arr = ['.numbers', '.weight-change', '.onebox'];

stored($(arr.join()), function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).is(arr[0])) {
        var num = index + 1 + ".";
        $(value).empty();
        $(value).append(num);
    }
    else if ($(this).is(arr[1]) || $(this).is(arr[2])) {
        myFunction();
        if ($(this).is(arr[1])) {
            $(this).attr("id", "weight" + index);
        }
        else if ($(this).is(arr[2])) {
            $(this).attr("id", "shipprice1box" + index);
        }
    }
});
```